# Looking for rows with duplicate fields where duplicates aren't valid - but there are multiple valid scenarios. Using DBVis/Oracle fwiw

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have the following data in a table of fiber customers. Note that a house can have multiple rooms with extra copies of each service (think multiple phone lines) but it cannot have multiple services of the same kind in the same room. So, in the below table, house 1 and 4 are both valid, but houses 2 and 3 both have a problem - they appear to have multiple services of the same type in "room 1."

| HOUSE | ROOM_NAME | SERVICE | ROOM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50001 |
| 1 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50001 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50003 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50004 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBTV | 50005 |
| 4 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50006 |
| 4 | Room 2 | FIBTE | 50007 |

You can see from the data that some of these multiple "room 1" records at the same house actually have different Room IDs. But the user can't see that, so they see it as two different services in the same room. I'm trying to find all the records with this issue.

So, I'm looking for all services located at houses where there are **multiple room IDs that match the same room name** (two "Room 1" entries with different IDs). The problem is, it's valid to have multiple records with the same house and room name (and room ID), as long as you don't have two copies of the SAME service in the same room.

The result I'm looking for is -

| HOUSE | ROOM_NAME | SERVICE | ROOM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50003 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50004 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBTV | 50005 |

House 2 has room IDs 50002 and 50003, which are both called "Room 1." House 3 has room IDs 50004 and 50005, which are also both called "Room 1" - but note that these two rooms don't have any services in common.

I tried this query -

```
Select HOUSE, ROOM_NAME, SERVICE, ROOM_ID

from COMM_SERVICES

where
(HOUSE, ROOM_NAME, SERVICE) in
(select HOUSE, ROOM_NAME, SERVICE
from COMM_SERVICES
group by HOUSE, ROOM_NAME, SERVICE
having count(*)>1)

order by HOUSE ASC
```

And got the result:

| HOUSE | ROOM_NAME | SERVICE | ROOM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50003 |

So it finds House 2 but omits House 3, and it doesn't show all services at House 2, only the ones where the same service exists in both rooms.

If I revise the query to instead use

```
where
(HOUSE, ROOM_NAME) in
(select HOUSE, ROOM_NAME
from COMM_SERVICES
group by HOUSE, ROOM_NAME
having count(*)>1)
```

Then I get this result:

| HOUSE | ROOM_NAME | SERVICE | ROOM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50001 |
| 1 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50001 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50002 |
| 2 | Room 1 | FIBTE | 50003 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBER | 50004 |
| 3 | Room 1 | FIBTV | 50005 |

This result correctly includes House 2 and House 3, but also incorrectly includes House 1, which has two different services in the same room with the same room ID, which is valid.

I feel like I'm going about this all wrong, but I can't think what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Why does house 3 fit your criteria? It has two different services in the same room_name. You mentioned this is ok, so why is that something you want to identify? Is it solely because that room_name has two different room_id values?

Comment: I've tried to clarify - House 3 is still a problem because it has two different rooms with the same name at the same location. Right now it *appears* fine to users because it looks like one room with two different services, but it's still bad data, and the problem would be exposed if a user added another service of the same type.